# Kendo Grid MVC Open Context Menu on Left Click

Tags: model-view-controller, menu, kendo-grid, row

I am using MVC Kendo Grid. First column has an icon which opens a right click context menu.  I want to left click this icon and open a context menu / menu.

Please note on individual row I want to perform some operation when selecting some operation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the event to show the context menu: `.ShowOn("click")`. See https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/ContextMenuBuilder#showonsystemstring for documentation and https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/contextmenu/configuration/showon for an example.